# How to put 'a is a subset of b'in coq?

Tags: coq

I tried to implement that S is a subset of Z using 
Infix "⊂" := (Included Z) (at level 70).
(our prof provided with this 
but when i try to write 
forall (S ⊂ Z), (insert theorem)
an error message pops as below

> Syntax error: ',' expected after [constr:open_binders] (in [constr:binder_constr]).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Only variables can appear in a quantifier.  You need to put the formula in a hypothesis inside the quantifier, like this:

```
forall S, S ⊂ Z -> (* Some property *)
```